# Phonegap inAppBrowser working only from start page

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

My problem that inAppBrowser working only from start page. I need to open external link in my application from one of many pages in flow. I want use for it inAppBrowser, but it open page without navigation bar and done button. If i trying add inAppBrowser to index.html it is works fine...

in index.html I open next page by 
    var ref = window.open("startNavigation.html", "_blank", "location=no");

in some.html I trying to open external windows with button by calling:
    window.open("http://google.html", '_self', 'location=yes');

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open it as long as you define Javascript on the html file header. Same way as in index. Best would be to define a javascript file and call it from each html file you want to open a webpage.